# MobileFirst Build not update JS and HTML changes

Tags: javascript, ios, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using MobileFirst 6.3.0 plugin, Xcode 7.3.1. Eclipse

On a Hybrid App, I did some changes to common resources, after the build the App, the changes were applied successfully on Android, but for iOS the were not applied. Debugging with Xcode Simulator, I saw the old code still remains.

I already did the following steps with no success results:

1. Remove the wlBuildResources and wlPreview directories.
2. Remove all the artifacts under the bin directory.

Anyone of you have any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your explanation how exactly did you do the build...

1. Make a change in the index.js file for example
2. Right-click on the "iphone" folder -> run as -> Xcode project (which will then open the updated project in Xcode for you to compile it and run in a simulator or physical device) or Right-click on the "applicationName" folder -> run as -> run on MobileFirst Development Server (after which you need to manually open the generated Xcode project (the iphone\native folder) in Xcode by yourself.

Comment: I did changes on HTML and Javascript files for an hybrid App, but when I recompile and test the App, the changes are not applied on iOS, only for Android the changes are applied.